# Using a batch file on Desktop to start shortcut on AllUsersDesktop

Tags: batch-file

I use a remote support program to access agent's computers to set them up to work with our dialer.

I use a script via that remote program that adds IE shortcuts to their desktop.  To make this script work for any variety of computer setups, the shortcuts are created on the AllUsersDesktop.

I also install a program (called Ventrilo) that creates a shortcut on the specific desktop they are on when I remote into their system.

I would like to add a batch file they can execute that will automatically open the shortcut to Ventrilo and open the IE shortcut on the AllUsersDesktop.

The batch file I have is as follows:

```
@echo off
start Ventrilo.lnk
start Shortcut.lnk
```

This opens Ventrilo but not the Shortcut.  I am certain it is because the Shortcut is on the AllUsersDesktop, while the shortcut to Ventrilo is not.  However, I cannot figure out how to use that start command in conjunction with %AllUserDesktop%

Answer (score 3):

```
%allusersprofile%\desktop\shortcut.lnk
```

Type set in a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can start IE by calling start on iexplore, no need to run the shortcut.

```
start iexplore
```

Alternatively GoughW's answer should do the trick to.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an end line at the end of your

```
start shortcut.lnk
```

in your batch file.